# GParted - Increase ext4 partition using unallocated space

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, gparted

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I resize my current ubuntu partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18523/how-do-i-resize-my-current-ubuntu-partition)
> [Making A Partition with Gparted - Unmount?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187183/making-a-partition-with-gparted-unmount)

This is a screenshot of my partitions. I want to extend the `/dev/sda5` partition to all unallocated space (27.03 GB).

[image]

I tried unmount the ext4 partition to increase it but i got this error message.

> The partition could not be unmounted from the following mount points:
>
> /
>
> Most likely other partitions are also mounted on these mount points. You are advised to unmount them manually.

Comment: Are you trying to increse the size of the drive Ubuntu is installd on and where is the screenshot ?

Comment: Sorry the system refuses to upload my screenshot as I am new on askubuntu ... I want to increase the size of ubuntu (ext4) partition, but cannot unmount it to resize.

Comment: Are you trying to increse the size of the drive Ubuntu is installd on ?

Comment: You cannot unmount the partition you have booted Ubuntu from. boot from a Live CD/DVD/USB and choose **Try Ubuntu**. Then use GParted.

Comment: Image Sorted :-) - the link was at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can't resize the partition Ubuntu is currently running from.

You need to boot the install media, LiveCD or USB drive, choose the option `Try Ubuntu without installing`. Then when it loads the desktop, you can run GParted and resize the partition as you want.